# Rails (/Rspec) (/Capibara): Test Icon is visible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm currently using Rails, Rspec and Capybara.

How would I test that an Icon is actually visible and coming through on the client side? Something like this:

```
<i class="ionicons ion-man"></i>
```

I've searched stack overflow for "Rspec Icons" and "Rails Test Icons" and haven't found an existing question that can answer this.

**edit:**

I don't want to show that the css is present and visible on the page, but whether the icon is coming down the asset pipeline. I just tested this solution and a passing test after 'breaking' the asset pipeline so that the icons come through as boxes. Perhaps my request is out of the ability of capybara?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`have_css`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/RSpecMatchers#have_css-instance_method) selector.

```
expect(page).to have_css('i.ion-man')
```

Comment: Same as the above comment

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a particular node (in your case `li`) with a specific class (in your case `ionicons`) exist and is also visible:

```
page.has_css?('li.ionicons', :visible => true)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only shows that the css is present and visible on the page, not whether the icon is coming down the pipeline. I just tested this solution and a passing test after 'breaking' the asset pipeline so that the icons come through as boxes. Perhaps my request is out of the ability of capybara?